# Why I cannot run an object file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

When I want to run a source code why this works :

```
gcc test.c -o test.o
```

then

```
./test.o
```

but this does not work :

```
gcc -c test.c
```

then

```
./test.o
```

and get this message

```
bash: ./test.o: Permission denied
```

Comment: An object file is not machine instructions. It is not intended to be run. It is intended to be linked. You should use `gcc test.c -o test`. Then you have a runnable file called `test`.

Comment: Take a good look a `man ld` and see what purpose it serves in creating the final elf-executable and see the answers (as well as Joachim's deleted one) below.

Comment: after `gcc test.c -o test.o`, you created an executable named `test.o` . It is not an object file.

Comment: Why are you expecting to be able to? Because the names are the same?

Comment: Not to be rude, but this is somehow _analogous_ to asking, why I can rename a .pdf to .doc but can't open the new file using _MSWord_. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry but today is my first day in gcc :))

Comment: @testme I already mentioned , I was not trying to be rude, just once incident came to my mind, hope no offense taken. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you are not creating an object file but an *executable* file. Object files are an intermediate file used as input file for the linker to create the executable file. That you name it with an `.o` suffix doesn't matter.

Secondly, due to tradition if you do not specify an output filename with the `-o` option the compiler frontend program and linker will create an executable named `a.out`.

But that's not all, because with the second example you are actually creating a real object file, and those are not executable. Like mentioned above, those needs to be passed to a separate linking step to create the executable file.

You either need to create an executable file:

```
gcc test.c
./a.out
```

*Or* you should link the object file into an executable file:

```
gcc -c test.c            # Create object file
gcc test.o -o test       # Use object file to create executable file
./test                   # Run the executable file
```

Answer (score 4):

You get that message because the compiler doesn't set the executable bit on object files, because - well, because they are not executable. If you set the executable bit manually and try to run it, you'll get something like "unknown executable format".

Now, it's not just a format problem - the point is that an object file is just half of the work to get something that can actually be executed. In particular, it's missing the *linking* step, where the linker finds unresolved references and patches them with the addresses from other object files - including the ones you don't specify explicitly, like the standard library - and generates a proper executable file, that the kernel knows how to load and execute.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you just *name* the resulting file `test.o` by using `-o`, it has been compiled assembled and linked.

In the second case you merely compiled and assemble, it can't run without being linked. See `gcc --h` or [Overall options for `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) for `-c`:

> `-c`
>
> Compile or assemble the source files, **but do not link**. **The linking stage simply is not done**. The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.
>       By default, the object file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix ‘.c’, ‘.i’, ‘.s’, etc., with ‘.o’.

```
Unrecognized input files, not requiring compilation or assembly, are ignored.
```

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

You need to link it and then execute it:

```
gcc -o a.out test.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an object file. This is not executable and need to be linked to become executable.

Try

`gcc -o test test.c` and run using `./test.out`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental question in gcc. Note that never using parameter -c when you want to get an executable file in single command such as

```
gcc -c xx.c yy.c -o new
```

.But you can get an executable file with -c in following commands

```
gcc -c xx.c yy.c
gcc xx.o yy.o -o new
```

It's equivalent to

```
gcc xx.c yy.c -o new
```